# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isPalindrome'

Tags: python

I'm new to Python thus the question,

I'm trying to solve a simple algorithmic problem of finding the longest palindromic substring given a string.

This is my code.

```
class Solution(object):

    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        curr = 0
        for i, c in enumerate(s):
            for j in range(len(s)):
                sub = s[i:i+j]
                if sub.isPalindrome():
                    curr = max(curr, len(sub))

        return curr

    def isPalindrome(self, s):
        for i, c in enumerate(s):
            if c != s[-i -1]:
                return False
        return True
```

I get the error,

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isPalindrome'
```

If I change the call to this,

```
 if isPalindrome(sub):
                    curr = max(curr, len(sub))
```

I get the following error,

```
NameError: global name 'isPalindrome' is not defined
```

Can someone help me understand what's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the method using the *self* reference. That would be:

```
if self.isPalindrome(sub):
      curr = max(curr, len(sub))
```

`sub.isPalindrome()` will not work because the method is not bound to the unicode/string object